# Adding up gravitational fields of infinitely many objects?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, universe, singularities

I'm reading a book introducing gravity and find something I don't understand. Please check the attached image. The sentence in red bracket claims that if one adding up gravitational fields of infinitely many objects, the total gravitational field depends on the order in which we add them.

I'm just wondering how do summation order affect the total gravitational field? Is this some mathematical magic in infinite series?[image]

Comment: I assume this is a reference to the fact the [Madelung Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madelung_constant) is conditionally convergent.

Comment: The issue pointed out in the text has been discussed on this site [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/430419/why-isnt-an-infinite-flat-nonexpanding-universe-filled-with-a-uniform-matter/) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/490829/ambiguity-in-applying-newtons-shell-theorem-in-an-infinite-homogeneous-universe?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: @jacob1729 Thank you. In Madelung constant case there exists both positive and negative charges so I can understand why order matters. But for gravity the masses should all be positive

Comment: It's because the gravitational forces due to these masses can be in different directions, and hence cancel.

Comment: @knzhou the specific issue arising with constant uniform density might be what they meant, but its somewhat hard to tell since the text sounds like its referring to a countably infinite number of discrete bodies.

Comment: @jacob1729 Sure, but I think the same conceptual issues arise whether it's continuous or countably infinite, as long as on large scales the density is approximately uniform.

Comment: Please do not post images of texts you want to quote, but *type it out instead* so it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/143136) instead.